# Unable to use returned value from another file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am very new to python and trying to build a solution using Python + Selenium.

1. I have created a module to initialize my webdriver:

DriverEngine.py:

```
import os

from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from MyFirstSeleniumPyProject.FrameworkEngine.Constants import BrowserConstants

class DriverInitialize:
    def InitializeChromeDriver(self):
        browser_name = BrowserConstants.Chrome
        print(browser_name)
        driver = DriverConfiguration.ConfigureChromeDriver(None)
        return driver

class DriverConfiguration:

    def ConfigureChromeDriver(self):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")
        # preferences
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {            
            'download.default_directory': get_download_path(),
            'profile': {
                'password_manager_enabled': False,
                'disable-popup-blocking': 'true'
            }
        })       

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
        return driver

def get_download_path():
    dir_path = os.getcwd()
    return dir_path
```

2. I'm trying to invoke above driver function in my test file:
   Chrome_Test.py

```
from MyFirstSeleniumPyProject.FrameworkEngine.Drivers import DriverEngine
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

class AssertGooglePage:
    def navigate_url(self,url):
        self.driver = DriverEngine.DriverInitialize.InitializeChromeDriver(None)
        self.driver.get(url)

AssertGooglePage.navigate_url(None, url="https://www.google.com")
```

3. ErrorLog:

```
C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\TestAutomation.Selenium.Practice\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/TestAutomation.Selenium.Practice/MyFirstSeleniumPyProject/Tests/Chrome_Test.py
Chrome
 
[WDM] - Current google-chrome version is 84.0.4147
[WDM] - Get LATEST driver version for 84.0.4147
[WDM] - Driver [C:\Users\user\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\84.0.4147.30\chromedriver.exe] found in cache
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\TestAutomation.Selenium.Practice\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/TestAutomation.Selenium.Practice/MyFirstSeleniumPyProject/Tests/Chrome_Test.py", line 10, in <module>
    my = AssertGooglePage.navigate_url(None, url="https://www.google.com")
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/TestAutomation.Selenium.Practice/MyFirstSeleniumPyProject/Tests/Chrome_Test.py", line 7, in navigate_url
    self.driver = DriverEngine.DriverInitialize.InitializeChromeDriver(None)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\TestAutomation.Selenium.Practice\MyFirstSeleniumPyProject\FrameworkEngine\Drivers\DriverEngine.py", line 11, in InitializeChromeDriver
    driver = DriverConfiguration.ConfigureChromeDriver(None)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\TestAutomation.Selenium.Practice\MyFirstSeleniumPyProject\FrameworkEngine\Drivers\DriverEngine.py", line 47, in ConfigureChromeDriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\TestAutomation.Selenium.Practice\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\TestAutomation.Selenium.Practice\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

4. When I use similar snippet in same file, it works perfectly:

```
from selenium import webdriver
#import chromedriver_binary
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

# Select webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

# Select page load time out
driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)

# Navigate to url
driver.get("https://www.google.com")

# Sleep
time.sleep(3)

# Assertion
isTitle = driver.title=="Google"
if(isTitle):
    print("Google page opened successfully!")
else:
    print("Google page did not opened successfully!")

driver.quit()
```

Can some one suggest what's wrong with my scripts?
Please Note: I am not keeping Chromedriver at any location instead downloading at run time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your script does not know where you Chrome Driver (Selenium) is located.

Try to use the following code to point Selenium to where you downloaded the Chrome Driver:

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe")`